# Is the sentence "we don't need to be what they want us to" correct without the "be" in the end?

Tags: sentence, omissibility, sentence-ends

The formal way to say the sentence would be "we don't need to be what they want us to be", but would it be acceptable and understandable in colloquial language (eg in a song) to say "we don't need to be what they want us to"?

Comment: Define "correct", "acceptable" (to whom?), and "understandable" (by whom?).

Comment: @Drew you got me there. I think my question is more like: would you think it's unusual and weird if you heard this sentence in a casual conversation or in a song?

Comment: It's intriguing that leaving out *be* sounds awkward, whereas not repeating the verbs *do, have, go, ask...* does not.

Comment: @AndrewLeach so in your opinion, it'd be better to not use the sentence like that? Sorry if I'm not following completely your logic.

Comment: I'm saying that omitting *be* (as you want to) seems awkward to me, but a sentence like "We don't need to ask what they want us to" is not. Why that should be so is an interesting question. The fact that you're asking the question you have indicates that you think omitting *be* is awkward: so don't do it! However, **why** omitting *be* is awkward is definitely an on-topic question.

Comment: It sounds okay to my American English ear—especially if it were in a lyric. *We don't need to be what they want us to / we don't need to do what they tell us to...*

Comment: There are two different verbs: need and want. Leaving off BE works only if there is repetition of the verb  in the first clause: **I need to be rich** but you **do not need to** [be rich].

Comment: A lyric is closer to a poem that to a sentence. You are free to play on. Play out. Play up. If you write songs and don't take chances ...